# Understanding the class expression __init__(${1:self})$0:

Tags: python, spyder

when using the new Spyder in Python's Anaconda, the `def __init__` can be auto-completed to

```
__init__(${1:self})$0:
```

I would like to know, wether this expression makes sense in this position (or if it is an error)and what it means.

Best regards

Comment: That looks like part of a shell script that generates Python code via parameter interpolation.

Comment: Can it be used (and is it useful) in Python like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autocompleted statement is not meaningful in Python's context. Actually this is a known bug and should have been fixed. Please refer to [this github issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/11237)